# Yii2 & PostgreSQL: How to create new jsonb() column and store existing column value

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2, jsonb

I have a table with a column `language`. I need to add a new column `languageb` and store the value from `language` column.

*Example:*

```
language | languageb
____________________
en       | {"en"}
ru       | {"ru"}
```

So, what I have:

```
$this->addColumn($this->tableName, 'languageb', 'jsonb');
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE ".$this->tableName." SET languageb = language;")->execute();
```

*Exception is:*

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  column "languageb" is 
of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. So what did you try?

Comment: `languageb = language::JSONB` jsonb passed as string (character varying in postgresql terms) so you have to add casting to your sql statement and your update statement has not got any `where` clause it will update all rows in table!

Comment: cske, when i run "yii migrate" i have: Exception: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "en" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: en